# Movie about afterlife, large towers with clothing and food

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I saw this movie (or maybe it was a TV show) a long time ago.

All I remember is a larger number of people waking up in water and making it to the shore, I want to say they died and are waking up in an afterlife, but again the details are hazy. I remember there were these large towers near the shore the people got food and clothing from.

I was young, so I'm thinking it came out before 2004.  That's live action, not animated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like Philip Jose Farmer's *Riverworld* books.  There have been, I believe,
two movies (2003 and 2010) so perhaps it's the earlier one [Riverworld (2003)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0310952/).
The premise is interesting, in that any characters from history
may show up to drive a subplot.

The first book, **To Your Scattered Bodies Go** might be of interest, too.

Comment: Yep the 2003 movie, I remember all of the naked people. I've been searching forever for this, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I saw this too. The movie ended kind of, not really resolving anything, with everybody on a kind of ship going down a river. I believe it was supposed to be the pilot for a series which was never made.